# What's the difference between "sudo -i" and "sudo su -"

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Both commands will log me in as root. I know there is a difference in what environment settings are set.

Which one do you use? Which one is better practice?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su

Comment: Why would you have program-A run program-B, when program-A can do everything you need? `sudo su` is common practice, but it's common practice *because people don't know any better*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`su` has only one purpose: to start a shell running as the given user (`root` by default).

`sudo` is a highly configurable program that lets you run *any* command as any user, with the configuration allowing the local administrator to place limits on what commands you can run using `sudo`, as well as which commands require your password.

`su` is (I believe) the older program which allows you to do anything the given user can do, which is often more than you *need*. `sudo` is safer in that it can be tailored to allow you *just* enough authority to run the commands you need, nothing more.

Comment: This is all true, but I'm not sure it addresses the OP's question. (As a fan of `sudo -i` and a hater re: `sudo su`, I'm happy to see the question asked, even if the forum selection wasn't on-point).

Answer (score 2):

http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

> The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed. sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell. The security policy shall initialize the environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what is present when a user logs in. The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.